# How to include checkbox value and associated label text in a jQuery array with line breaks after multiple implode values

Tags: php, jquery, implode

I am trying to create an array combining both the label and value of an input field. The problem is my jQuery code combines ALL labels and input values, not just those which are selected. The code I am trying is as below:

**jQuery:**

```
let values = [];
        
$("label[for='servicelist-label[]'], input[name='servicelist-details[]']").each(function() {
    values.push($(this).text());
    values.push($(this).val());
});
```

**PHP Implode Code:**

```
$serviceinfo = implode("",array_map(function($i){
               return implode("<br>",$i);
               },array_chunk($_POST['servicelist'],2)));
```

**PHP Form Elements:**

```
<label for="servicelistlabel[]" >Service 1: </label><input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelistcheckbox[]" id="servicelist1" value="Area 1"><br>
<label for="servicelistlabel[]" >Service 2: </label><input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelistcheckbox[]" id="servicelist2" value="Area 2"><br>
<label for="servicelistlabel[]" >Service 3: </label><input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelistcheckbox[]" id="servicelist3" value="Area 3"><br>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, or a jQuery problem? Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close, you just need to switch the implode-separators:

```
$serviceinfo = implode("<br>",array_map(function($i){
               return implode(" ",$i);
               },array_chunk($_POST['servicelist'],2)));
```

This should result in the desired output.

**Edit:**

Ok I now know what you want to achieve. There are a couple of problems with the JS part. I will go over your code real quick

```
$("label[for='servicelistlabel[]'], input[name='servicelistcheckbox[]']:checked").each(function() {
   values.push($(this).text());
   values.push($(this).val());
});
```

- You are iterating over both, label and checkbox at the same time.
- `$(this)` is the label at one iteration, the checkbox in the next iteration.
- Because of that `$(this).val()` is empty the first iteration since the label has no value.
- `$(this).text()` is empty the next iteration since the checkbox has no text.
- This results in an array structure like `["Label", "", "", "Value"]` for each checkbox you have checked.
- Also, the `for=""` attribute in a label has to match the `id=""` attribute of the checkbox, or else the label will not trigger on click.

**How to solve?**

https://jsfiddle.net/5ubnes1k/
Take a look at this fiddle.
I put each label/checkbox-combo into a `div.checkbox` to have an easier time selecting it.

```
let values = [];
$(".checkbox").each(function() {
  const label = $(this).find('label');
  const checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');

  if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
    values.push(label.text(), checkbox.val());
  }
});
```

Now we only iterate over the `.checkbox` divs, selecting the label and checkbox inside. If the checkbox is checked, we push the label-text and checkbox-value into the array. The output is something like: `["Service 1: ", "Service1", "Service 3: ", "Service3"]`

With this array structure you should be able to get the wanted result with the `implode` part of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that originally but it results in each value on a separate line.

Comment: This is the original code I am trying, yet it does not seem to work with my array: https://3v4l.org/Pj8nd

Comment: https://3v4l.org/IetPo gives me the output: Element 1, Element 2<br>Element 3, Element 4<br>Element 5, Element 6. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you @clash, this is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you for helping me see my problem was with the array. I now understand how it should work!

Answer (score 0):

@clash was on the right track with the fact I needed to switch the implode separators. In the end my array_chunk needed to have the value of 4 and the line breaks needed to be in different locations in order for it to work. Here is the working code for anyone else with a similar problem:

```
$serviceinfo = implode(array_map(function($i){
               return implode(" ", $i);
               },array_chunk($_POST['servicelist'],4)),"<br>");
```

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by @clash, my implode code will not work in PHP8. It looks like my array is incorrect. Basically I am trying to include both the label AND checkbox value in the array, however all of the labels are being added regardless of whether the checkbox is checked or not.

This is a jQuery problem I do not know how to solve. The code used is below:

**PHP Form Elements:**

```
<label for="servicelistlabel[]" >Service 1: </label><input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelistcheckbox[]" id="servicelist1" value="Service1"><br>
<label for="servicelistlabel[]" >Service 2: </label><input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelistcheckbox[]" id="servicelist2" value="Service2"><br>
<label for="servicelistlabel[]" >Service 3: </label><input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelistcheckbox[]" id="servicelist3" value="Service3"><br>
```

**jQuery:**

```
let values = [];
        
$("label[for='servicelistlabel[]'], input[name='servicelistcheckbox[]']:checked").each(function() {
   values.push($(this).text());
   values.push($(this).val());
});
```

**PHP Implode Function** (incorrect):

```
$serviceinfo = implode(array_map(function($i){
               return implode(" ", $i);
               },array_chunk($_POST['servicelist'],4)),"<br><br>");
```

Comment: Careful: passing (array, separator) in the implode function is deprecated and is removed in PHP8: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
Also, chunking by 4 if you want a set of 2 seems incorrect. Maybe the array is not build correctly?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It must be my array as I am passing multiple values even when they are not checked within my form. I will post the php and jQuery to show what I am using.

Comment: I have updated my answer just now. It may be a good idea to update you question, not this answer, to give users who come here a better idea of what your problem actually was.